# Laravel 8 symlink on hosting returned 404 but files is present on filesystem

Tags: php, laravel

I have project currently hosted on hostinger.
Everything went well except the files that are unable to display when it's already hosted.

Hosting provider: Hostinger

Tried various fixes like
-rm public/storage
-php artisan optimize:clear
-php artisan storage:link

Files uploaded are found in 'storage/app/public/files'.

However the when accessed from domain, the path returns to 404 as the path doesn't exist meanwhile working on localhost.

File tree looks like this:

```
-domain.ml
 - laravel
    -storage (755)
        -app
          -public
            -files
              -pdf-test_32.pdf (655)
              
    -public (symlink pointed to 
              /storage/app/public)
        -files 
     
  -public_html
    -index.php
```

Files are exactly working on localhost using this path

http://localhost:800/storage/files/pdf-test_32.pdf 200 Ok

https://domain.ml/storage/files/pdf-test_32.pdf 404

Just needed a little hand about how to resolve as various blogs and fixes didn't work as I've tried.

Comment: Your other assets are loading as exacted? css,. JS. Images?

Comment: Yes sir. Just the uploaded images have the problem.